# Password/Authentication for users inside App on iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, authentication

my goal is to give my customers an option to lock their App's Data, so when they give their iPad/iPhone to someone else for an extended period of time, users can't access or accidentally  look at confidential data.
[Some Background: It's a medical Application where physicians/staff-members would give iPads to patients. Now the patients are supposed to access some contents, yet shouldn't be able to look at other patients data]

So far, I have a password inside my App. But when a staff-member forgets and wants to reset it, the only thing I can do is "deletion of the whole database". I have a Disclaimer telling people to store their password somewhere, but this is still not the optimal user experience.

Is there anyway I could authenticate the user via his Apple-Password? This way only the person knowing the Devices-Account password can access the data and can always reset the Apple-Password with Apple.

PS: Server-Solutions, like having a User-Password pair with reset-via-mail on a server of mine is out of the question, since it would add to much complexity for the users and in many medical situations the Device shouldn't have access to the web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple thoughts:

1. I am not aware of any native public API to authentication using Apple password.
2. If your app is enterprise app, possibly you can use native private API. I would recommend to disassemble AppStore and check how does it do authentication then
3. You can also to try to access to some Apple web page which requires authentication and pass to it apple account and password and see what it will return. If it authenticated correctly, then you are fine and you can reset a password.

   To make it secure, you will need to ask a user to enter it for a first time, so you can encrypt your encryption keys using authentication material (so you can decrypt encryption key later on).

   However, I am not very big fan of this solution, since you can change Apple password and you will be stuck in such case.
4. Server solution is the best option and it's not that complex. Another option is Forgot password. You ask something what administrator know ("What is your first pet?") and he enters the answer when your application is configured and this answer could be used later to unlock your app.

P.S. And the best solution at the end (which is absolutely shameless self advertisement). A startup which I am part of ([SpydrSafe](http://www.spydrsafe.com)) works on the product which solves exactly your problem. In fact, healthcare is one of the verticals which whom we actively works. If you are interested, contact me (my email is in profile)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I totally forgot about the "What is your first pet?" idea!
I'll add that and if the user still can't get it right I can still offer to delete the database.

Answer (score 0):

if you authenticate the user via apple password, and they forget their apple password, then in order for them to retrieve that password is by reset-via-email .... so either way you are stuck with that dilemma.

As for actually using your apple password, no.

Best way to get what you want is to have the password stored somewhere in real life. Like another computer that the doctors can report to and ask for passwords or just don't forget the password.